# java fx: scene's lookup method

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx-2, javafx-8

If a node is having fx:id (say a) as well as normal id(css id) (say b). If lookup is used to search this node:

Node node=scene.lookup("#a")

The above statement returns null. But if there is no css id corresponding to node in discussion, then above statement returns the correct node.

While using the below given statement always returns the correct result:

Node node=scene.lookup("#b")

Can anyone please explain why lookup method is behaving so weirdly?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<GridPane hgap="14.0" maxHeight="+Infinity" maxWidth="+Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="223.0" prefWidth="323.0" vgap="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <children>
    <VBox maxHeight="+Infinity" maxWidth="+Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" spacing="7.0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
      <children>
            <HBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT">
               <children>
              <Label fx:id="headerMessage" text="message" textAlignment="LEFT" wrapText="true">
                <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
                </font>
              </Label>
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" spacing="5.0">
               <children>
              <Label fx:id="qty" text="details" textAlignment="LEFT" wrapText="true">
                <font>
                  <Font size="12.0" />
                </font>
              </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="qtyT" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" spacing="5.0">
               <children>
                  <Label fx:id="name" text="details" textAlignment="LEFT" wrapText="true">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <TextField fx:id="nameT" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <HBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" spacing="5.0">
               <children>
                  <Label fx:id="remarks" text="details" textAlignment="LEFT" wrapText="true">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <TextArea fx:id="remarksT" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="149.0" wrapText="true" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
      </children>
    </VBox>
    <HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="+Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="253.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
      <children>
        <Pane maxWidth="+Infinity" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
        <Button id="cancel-button" fx:id="cancelButton" cancelButton="true" minWidth="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cancel" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
          <HBox.margin>
            <Insets />
          </HBox.margin>
        </Button>
        <HBox fx:id="okParent" alignment="CENTER">
          <children>
            <Button id="ok-button" fx:id="okButton" minWidth="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Ok" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
              <HBox.margin>
                <Insets left="14.0" />
              </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
          </children>
        </HBox>
      </children>
    </HBox>
  </children>
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="+Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <padding>
    <Insets bottom="14.0" left="14.0" right="14.0" top="14.0" />
  </padding>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="+Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
    <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" vgrow="NEVER" />
  </rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
```

In the above fxml, lookup works fine on fxml id's for the nodes which don't have any css id. If css id is present, then it return nulls

```
Label headerMessage = (Label) alertStage.getScene().lookup("#headerMessage");
                final TextField qty = (TextField) alertStage.getScene().lookup("#qtyT");
                Label name = (Label) alertStage.getScene().lookup("#name");
                final TextArea remarksT = (TextArea) alertStage.getScene().lookup("#remarksT");
                final TextField nameT = (TextField) alertStage.getScene().lookup("#nameT");
```

lookup method fails only for given below statement.

```
Button okButton = (Button) alertStage.getScene().lookup("#okButton");
```

Comment: That is strange. I am sure with `fx:id`, it should always return `null`. Can you add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) depicting this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** - After the OP added the MCVE

Digging into the matter. I got a simple statement written deep inside the documentation of FXML which explains about the behaviour. Actually, the fx:id is assigned as the `default id` of the control / layout by calling the `setId()`.

*Unless overridden, `fx:id` stays as the `default id` of the object*.

From [Introduction To FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#variable_resolution) :

> Assigning an fx:id value to an element creates a variable in the document's namespace that can later be referred to by variable dereference attributes, such as the "toggleGroup" attribute shown above, or in script code, discussed in a later section. **Additionally, if the object's type defines an "id" property, this value will also be passed to the objects setId() method.**

The `lookup()` is doing its job perfectly and is working for the `CSS selectors` and not on `fx:id`.